# How long will Mailchimp keep a member on a list in pending status?

Tags: list, mailchimp, status

I'm adding a member to a MailChimp list and periodically checking for their status to change from pending to subscribed.  Once the status changes I add them to a master list (a second MailChimp list).

I'm wondering how long MailChimp keeps the person's status as 'pending' if they don't respond to the confirmation email.  Wil they eventually get deleted or have their status changed to 'unsubscribed'?

Answer (score 0):

A subscriber can be in 'pending' status forever. They don't change to another status after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Forever... meaning as long as your same account is active :-)